# Removing duplicate arrays of an array : javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with javascript arrays, where i have an array of arrays like,

```
var arr = [ 
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],  
  [ 3.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0192222, 33.5778921 ],
  [ 73.0192222, 33.5778921 ]];
```

There, i needed to remove the duplicate arrays. I have tried this method but it didn't worked for me, may be i am missing or doing something wrong.

```
var distinctArr = Array.from(new Set(arr));
```

Although this method works only for array of objects. If someone can help, please do help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Specify your problem because I guess you want to remove **whole rows** of this array of arrays, not separate elements. If so - it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following approach.

```js
var arr = [ { person: { amount: [1,1] } }, { person: { amount: [1,1] } }, { person: { amount: [2,1] } }, { person: { amount: [1,2] } }, { person: { amount: [1,2] } }];

   hash = [...new Set(arr.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)))].map(v => JSON.parse(v));
   
   document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(hash, null, 2)}</pre>`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really worked. any idea what should be done for the array of kind var array = [  { person: { amount: [1,1] } },
{ person: { amount: [1,1] } }, 
{ person: { amount: [2,1] } },
{ person: { amount: [1,2] } },
{ person: { amount: [1,2] } }]; ??

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan Do you still have problem with this?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 3):

Lodash is great lib for doing this little things.

[uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqWith) with compare [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqWith) should resolve your problem.

```
var arr = [ 
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],  
  [ 3.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0191641, 33.5720131 ],
  [ 73.0192222, 33.5778921 ],
  [ 73.0192222, 33.5778921 ]];

_.uniqWith(arr,_.isEqual)

return -> [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```